# How buyTokenPercentageFee is calculated in 0x

Tags: blockchain, 0x

I am using a 0x Quote API to convert BUSD to USDC by exploring the feeRecipient and buyTokenPercentageFee but have confusion in the calculation.

Initial Quote without **buyTokenPercentageFee**

> Request

```
https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=BUSD&sellAmount=100000000000000000000
```

> Response

```
  {
    "chainId": 56,
    "price": "0.9997365742860093",
    "estimatedPriceImpact": "0",
    "value": "0",
    "gasPrice": "5000000000",
    "gas": "250000",
    "estimatedGas": "250000",
    "protocolFee": "0",
    "minimumProtocolFee": "0",
    "buyTokenAddress": "0x8ac76a51cc950d9822d68b83fe1ad97b32cd580d",
    "buyAmount": "99973657428600930000",
    "sellTokenAddress": "0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56",
    "sellAmount": "100000000000000000000",
    }
```

The buyAmount am receiving is 99973657428600930000 (99.97 in ether)

For the same quote if I apply buyTokenPercentageFee as 1 the quote I receive is

> Request

```
https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=BUSD&sellAmount=100000000000000000000&feeRecipient=0xa8aac589a67ecfade31efde49a062cc21d68a64e&buyTokenPercentageFee=1
```

> Response

```
{
    "chainId": 56,
    "price": "0.009996",
    "estimatedPriceImpact": "98.9299",
    "value": "0",
    "gasPrice": "5000000000",
    "gas": "255000",
    "estimatedGas": "255000",
    "protocolFee": "0",
    "minimumProtocolFee": "0",
    "buyTokenAddress": "0x8ac76a51cc950d9822d68b83fe1ad97b32cd580d",
    "buyAmount": "50479800000000000000",
    "sellTokenAddress": "0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56",
    "sellAmount": "100000000000000000000"
   }
```

The buyAmount am receiving is 50479800000000000000 (50.47 in ether). Which does not look like 1% of buyAmount. The percentage its applying is nearly ~50%.

So if anyone can explain how its been calculated will be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from 0x community.

> 1 = 100%, which has the effect of splitting the amount received 50/50

> For 1%, it should be .01.